# Use ARKit to add object to specific point in real world

Tags: iphone, arkit

For example I want to put some virtual shape on the top of the Eiffel Tower using ARKit. 
So when user stands in specified area - approximately 3 km from the tower and looking on the tower through his iPhone he can see this shape.

Is it possible? And if so - how it can be theoretically done?

Comment: Are you able to achive this? looking for something similar. wondering how snapchat does this for Jeff koons models?

Comment: Take a look at github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation - I tried it

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, not possible. Currently Apple's ARKit has no support for object persistence so even if someone catalogued all the interesting points on Earth, you still wouldn't be able to tell where the user's phone was in relation to that point in 6DOF (i.e. position+orientation) when the AR session started up.

Comment: What do you think about this project https://github.com/ProjectDent/ARKit-CoreLocation

Comment: The demo looks fun although it's hard to say how useful this would actually be. But keep in mind it's basically a 2D map injected into AR space based on geolocation, so there's no tech there that would allow you to have any fine-grained control over object placement or y-axis awareness.

Comment: any idea on how snapchat achive it with jeff koons project?